# How do I convert Foreach statement into linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq

how to convert below foreach into linq expression?

```
var list = new List<Book>();

foreach (var id in ids)
{
    list.Add(new Book{Id=id});
}
```

Comment: Any reason to write such simple statement as a linq expression? It's probably more readable as a foreach.

Comment: Resharper does this for you with one click :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward:

```
var list = ids.Select(id => new Book { Id = id }).ToList();
```

Or if you prefer query syntax:

```
var list = (from id in ids select new Book { Id = id }).ToList();
```

Also note that the `ToList()` is only necessary if you really need `List<Book>`. Otherwise, it's generally better to take advantage of Linq's lazy evaluation abilities, and allow the `Book` objects objects to only be created on demand.

Comment: Though I wouldnt call this LINQ syntax. 'from x in ids select new Book { Id = x }' feels more like LINQ.

Comment: @RandRandom This is definitely LINQ syntax, it's just LINQ method syntax as opposed to query syntax.  However, both still use (in this case), Linq-to-objects.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx

Comment: @RandRandom Added query syntax for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = ids.Select(id => new Book(id)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is in case the Book has such constructor.