# List Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have classes like this:

```
class Customer
{
    list<Orders> orders;
}

class Order
{
    public list<Address> ShiptoAddress;
}

class MyOrderInfo
{
   Order _order = null;

   public MyOrderInfo(Order ord)
   {
       _order = ord;
   } 

   public string Address1
   {
       get { return _order.ShiptoAddress[0].Value; }
   }
}
```

And in `main()` I have following code:

```
var myData = CustomerObj.orders.Select(x => new MyOrderInfo(x));
```

Can anyone help me to understand above line? When I debug, and watch value of `myData`, to my surprise it has "Address1" set with xxxx value. How is it working? I have couple of other properties in MyOderInfo class with

```
get { return _order.ShiptoAddress[xxx].Value; }
```

and all of them has proper value.... where is set? how is this code working?

Comment: What about it don't you understand?

Comment: Write it as a for each loop and compare it to the linq (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193898/how-do-i-convert-foreach-statement-into-linq-expression)

Comment: @sous2817 : i tried to convert it to foreach but ...can you please convert that line to foreach example...

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the signature for `Select`:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector
)
```

your linq query (including generic arguments the compiler inferred) is:

```
orders.Select<Order, MyOrderInfo>(x => new MyOrderInfo(x));
```

So, from the arguments, it's taking an `IEnumerable<Order>` and returning an `IEnumerable<MyOrderInfo>`.  The `Func` you pass into the `Select` should be doing just that:

```
x => new MyOrderInfo(x)
```

This is just an anonymous method, shorthand for a method you'd write.  A full method written out that could be substituted in here would look like:

```
public MyOrderInfo GetOrderInfo(Order x)
{
    return new MyOrderInfo(x);
}
```

and `MyOrderInfo` has a constructor that takes an `Order`, so it all compiles fine.

---

`Address1` has a getter, so you can think of it like a method here (which it really is).  Whenever you access `Address1`, its going to give you `_order.ShiptoAddress[0].Value;`.  `_order` was instantiated in the constructor, so as long as it has at least one item in its `ShipToAddress`, it'll work.

Comment: @Jonesoplis: nice explanation...make sense...but still i wonder how it set the values of MyOderInfo Class? MyOderInfo's Address1 and all other properties sets automatically. how?

Comment: i added a bit more

Comment: @Jonseopolis: ok. got it. thanks.....i want to learn this more, do you know any website where they have detail explanation....I googled i didn't find anything useful.

Comment: im a big fan of [pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/learn?aid=701j0000001heIFAAY&promo=&oid=&utm_source=&utm_medium=&utm_campaign=&utm_content=&utm_term=&gclid=Cj0KEQjw4827BRDJvpbVuKvx-rIBEiQA2_CzsNkbxLQBB19Cj3HwySkGl2W_d4xv-HzXrAl3cn8AZwkaAnug8P8HAQ).  training videos on anything you could just about want

Answer (score 0):

Linq queries are tricky to debug.  Effectively what they create is a set of "wrappers" around the original data, so it's not apparent just by digging in the debugger what the actual result will be.

The best way to see the the result is to *materialize the query*.  The simplest way to do that is to call `ToArray` or `ToList` and hydrate the query into a concrete data structure.  You can either do that in the program itself, or in the watch/immediate window, with the caveat that calling `ToList` creates the results *each time* so you may iterate the source data multiple times, which could be a problem.