# How can one covert this foreach loop to a LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I'm a beginner with LINQ.

How can I convert this to a LINQ statement?

```
List<Foo> myList = new List<Foo>();
myList.AddRange(// here I add my items);

foreach (Foo x in myList)
{
    if (x.IsRequired() == false) throw new Exception();
}
```

to a LINQ statement? Like:

```
myList.ForEach(x => //something here);
```

I tried the following but that didn't work for me.

```
myList.ForEach(x => if (x.IsRequired() == false) throw new Exception());
```

Comment: [ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a _LINQ_ statement, it's a method of `List` collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert Foreach statement into linq expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193898/how-do-i-convert-foreach-statement-into-linq-expression)

Comment: What type does `IsRequired()` return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say

```
if (MyList.Any(x => x.IsRequired() == false))
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

> IsRequired() It's a method that returns a Boolean

so you can also shorten

```
if (MyList.Any(x => !x.IsRequired()))
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Or simply `(!MyList.Any(x => x.IsRequired()))`

Comment: Well i think `IsRequired()` is not a method.It's a `Property`

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava - Oh! that's why OP has called it like this `IsRequired()` ?

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava Seeing as it's a method in OP's original code and we have no information that would suggest that it's not, I'd say it's safe to assume that it's a method.

Comment: IsRequired() It's a method that returns a Boolean

Comment: This solution works but the problem is it will not tell me which Foo in myList is required in case that an exception has been thrown ?

Comment: @HappyBird Then that is a different requirement and you should modify your question accordingly.

Comment: @HappyBird assignments are allowed in an if clause: `Foo f;
            if ((f = usecases.FirstOrDefault(x=> !x.IsRequired)) != null)
            {
                throw new Exception(f.Information);
            }`

Comment: @RahulSingh you have broken the logic, the correct alternative is     `!MyList.All(x => x.IsRequired())`

Comment: @Rimp - Oh really? I guess you have not read the question properly yet!

Answer (score 1):

The answer that fubo gave is good if you just want to see if any of the elements in your list is not required. If you want to get the actual element(s), you can do it like this:

### First Element

```
Foo notRequired = MyList.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.IsRequired());
if ( notRequired != null)
{
    // Do something with `notRequired`
}
```

## All Elements

```
IEnumerable<Foo> notRequired = MyList.Where(x => !x.IsRequired());
if (notRequired.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var v in notRequired)
    {
        // Do something with `v`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Officially `ForEach` is not a LINQ statement. It usually only works for Lists.

From your code I assume that you want to throw an exception if any of the `Foo` objects in `MyList` has a false `IsRequired`value.

You statement would be:

```
if (MyList.Any(foo => !foo.IsRequired))
    throw new Exception();
```

In words: if any of the foo elements in `MyList` has a false IsRequired value, throw a new `Exception`

The nice thing from using Any instead of first creating a list before checking, is that if you have an IEnumerable, and one of the first elements in the list would throw an exception, the rest of your list would not have been created in vain. See [StackOverflow: What are the benefits of deferred execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq)

**Later you wrote:**

> The problem is that I want to find all Foo elements in myList which
>   are not required. It's seems not possible with the Any method, it will
>   fail on the first one.

If you want to find all Foo elements in the list that are not required, you still can use Linq, using Enumerable.Where:

```
var notRequiredFoos = myList
    .Where(elementInList => !elementInList.IsRequired);
```

usage:

```
foreach (var notRequiredFoo in notRequiredFoos)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Foo element {notRequiredFoo.ToString} is not required");
}
```

Or if you want to throw an exception as soon as you found one, Linq will still help you: `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`

```
var notRequiredFoo= myList
    .Where(elementInList => !elementInList.IsRequired);
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (notRequiredFoo != null)
{   // we found a Foo that is not required
    throw new MyException(notRequiredFoo);
}
// else: all Foos are required
```

Again, you still don't have to check all elements in the list, it will stop as soon as one is found.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer, very descriptive. The problem is that I want to find all Foo elements in myList which are not required. It's seems not possible with the Any method, it will fail on the first one.

Comment: @HappyBird I posted an answer, where you can get all elements which are not required. It can be fitted into the if-statement. Have a look

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments and the additional information :

> The problem is that I want to find all Foo elements in myList which are not required. It's seems not possible with the Any method, it will fail on the first one.

Assuming `Foo` has some information that you would like to pass to your exception like a `string Information` you could get all of them assign them to a new list and check then for `Any()`. and do all that in the If-Clause:

```
List<Foo> temp = new List<Foo>();

if ((temp = MyList.Where(x=>!x.IsRequired()).ToList()).Any())
{
    // now pass the information of them all into the exception
    throw new Exception(String.Join("\t", temp.Select(y=>y.Information)));
}
```