# How to convert a foreach statement to LINQ using C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert a `foreach` statement into `LINQ` in C#.

- There is a class called `Unit` with three attributes `A`, `B` and `C`.
- There is a `List<Unit>` called `GetUnit`.

The following code is:

- to find the value of `C` if `A`equals to a `string` and
- assign `C` to `string`,

Is it possible to convert it to a `LINQ` statement?

```
foreach (Unit item in GetUnit)
{
    if (item.A == "This is a string")
    {
        string AAA = item.C;
    }
}
```

Comment: this code does nothing.with AAA.

Comment: Tools like JetBrains Resharper do suggest such conversions for you. Be aware that changing from C# code to LINQ is a change in behavior. The evaluation may happen at a different point in time unless you use `.ToList()`.

Comment: I would suggest looking up `.Where(..)` and `.ToList().ForEach(...)`

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why? I don't see any benefit of using Linq here (outside code obfuscation).

Comment: As others have mentioned it would be easier to help you convert it to LINQ if we knew the point of it. A bit more context would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* do:

```cs
var AAA = GetUnit.FirstOrDefault(item => item.A == "This is a string")?.C;
```

assuming you only expect one match, but... personally I'd just use the `foreach` and `if`.

(note: the `?.C` here returns `null` if there is no match, or `.C` of the match found otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

You want to find items *where* the property `A` matches `This is a string` and from each match, *select* their `C` property, hence:

```
var strings = GetUnit()
    .Where(i => i.A == "This is a string")
    .Select(i => i.C);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Marc Gravell's answer, you could use the [null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) like:

```
var AAA = GetUnit.FirstOrDefault(item => item.A == "This is a string")?.C ?? "Nothing found";
```

or even

```
var AAA = GetUnit.FirstOrDefault(item => item.A == "This is a string")?.C ?? throw new Exception("Nothing found");
```

Of course you should throw a more descriptive exception that fits your use case.

Comment: If you go and throw, it shouldn't be a general `Exception` but a more specific one, though. And you only should in the first place, if that _is_ a literal exception. Don't try and control flow by exception.

Comment: It was an example to show how the null coalescing operator could be used. Which exception to throw is out of scope of this question/answer as that depends on the overall context and system.

Comment: I did not criticize the `??` part. If you suggest throwing an Exception, then yes it _is_ in scope of the answer.

Comment: See also: [Things to Avoid When Throwing Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions#things-to-avoid-when-throwing-exceptions) : _" ... Do not throw System.Exception, System.SystemException, System.NullReferenceException, or System.IndexOutOfRangeException intentionally from your own source code."_

Comment: I have added clarity to my answer. And just to be clear, I am fully aware that you should never throw Exception, but choose a more descriptive/appropriate one.

Comment: IMO it would be better to just use `First(...)` here, and let the framework provide the expected exception

Comment: @MarcGravell Again it depends on the context and overall design of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the given answers, you can read/follow these two resources to gain knowledge:

- [SO question] [How do I convert Foreach statement into linq expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193898/how-do-i-convert-foreach-statement-into-linq-expression)
- [MS Docs] [Convert a foreach loop to LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/convert-foreach-linq?view=vs-2019)